# Why Yagel relates to Yaakov and Yismach to Israel

Tags: tehilim-psalms

In the Psalms, 14:7: "מי יתן מציון ישועת ישראל בשוב ה' שבות עמו יגל יעקב ישמח ישראל."Oh that the salvation of Israel were come out of Zion! When the LORD turneth the captivity of His people, let Jacob rejoice, let Israel be glad." This verse also appears in Tefilat Maariv. What is the difference between Jacob and Israel and what is the difference between Yigal and Yishmach? And why is Yagel attributed to Yaakov and Yismach to Israel?

Comment: Interesting: Chomat Anakh, Malbim Beur Hamilot (ad loc.).

Comment: Shabbos Mincha we say אברהם יגל

Comment: And Yitzhak Yeranen. We can add to the question: what is the difference between Yagel and Yeranen, and why each is attributed to each of the Avos?